# How to leave overlapping images in the same position?

Tags: html, css

I'm recreating the incila instagram page, I need to overlay the images of the **<figure** **class** **=** **"slide">** element, because afterwards I will put an animation, but I can't overlay the images, I've tried everything, as I'm a beginner I couldn't.

How can I do this?

```
.slide{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-left: 151px !important;
    margin-top: -521.5px !important;
}
```

```css
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
body{

    background-color: #fafafa;
}

.content{

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}
.container-login{
    
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

    border:1px solid;
    border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.img-perfil{

    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 92px;
    margin: 20px;
}
.not{
    background-color: #0095fe;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 279.08px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.container-trocar-conta{

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.change{
    margin-left: 2px;
   
    color:#0095fe;
    font-weight: bold;

}
.slide{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-left: 151px !important;
    margin-top: -521.5px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Instagram Inicial</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
    
            <div class="container-img-cel">
                <img class="cel"src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/home-phones.png/43cc71bb1b43.png">
                <figure class="slide">
                    <img class="foto" src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshot4.jpg/842fe5699220.jpg"/>
                    <img class="foto" src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshot1.jpg/d6bf0c928b5a.jpg"/>
                    <img class="foto" src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshot2.jpg/6f03eb85463c.jpg"/>
                    <img class="foto" src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshot3.jpg/f0c687aa6ec2.jpg"/>
                    <img class="foto" src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshot5.jpg/0a2d3016f375.jpg"/>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="container-login">
                <img class="img-logo" src="https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/instagram-logo-17.png">
                <div class="img">
                    <img class="img-perfil" src="https://cdn.cmjornal.pt/images/2019-06/img_432x244$2019_06_25_12_54_40_863705.jpg">
                </div>
                <a href="#"class="not">Continuar como dog ?</a>
                <div class="container-trocar-conta">
                    <p>Não é  dog ?</p>
                    <a class="change" href="#"> Trocar de conta</a>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `position: absolute;` for each `img` in `figure`. Just add it to your css. `.foto { position: absolute; }`

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the css of the whole frame with the .slide class, not the individual pictures.

You could give each picture a (second) unique class and and set each picture's position indivually. The overlapping can then be achieved by setting `position: absolute;` on each of the images altough this can bring some positioning problems.

So instead of using .slide, change the images like this

```
 <figure class="slide">
                    <img class="foto_1" src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshot4.jpg/842fe5699220.jpg"/>
                    <img class="foto_2" src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshot1.jpg/d6bf0c928b5a.jpg"/>
                    <img class="foto_3" src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshot2.jpg/6f03eb85463c.jpg"/>
                    <img class="foto_4" src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshot3.jpg/f0c687aa6ec2.jpg"/>
                    <img class="foto_5" src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshot5.jpg/0a2d3016f375.jpg"/>
 </figure>
```

And then create a seperate CSS entry for every image like this

```
.foto_1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px
}

.foto_2{
    position: absolute;
    left: -250px
}
```

Where the amount of `left: -?px` increases by the width of the image each foto.

Comment: Thanks, it works by adding the position absolute to each element, but I don't understand, why doesn't it work by generally adding the "class = foto"?

Comment: For example:

.foto{
     position: absolute;
}

Comment: Now it works adding only in .foto, thanks!